# Initial Step Size for NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I am using Mathematica to numerically integrate a numerically-defined function (from an interpolation and data).  This function has a sequence of somewhat unevenly spaced sharp peaks which dominate the integral.  When I use NIntegrate, the initial sampling doesn't pick up all of the the sharp peaks, and hence, the total value of the integral is wrong.

I would like to set the initial step size used by NIntegrate to be something small enough that it will find all of the relevant peaks.  However, I would prefer not to use a numerical integration method with a fixed sampling size, as the adaptive features are beneficial in actually determining the contribution from each peak.

One option, of course, is to break the integral up into a series of sequentially evaluated integrals; however, as the peaks are unevenly spaced, this would be time-consuming.  I'd much prefer setting the initial spacing if that's possible.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

(The specific function to be integrated is not very important, and since it is interpolated, I did not attach it here but if there's a need for it I can provide a sample.)

Comment: If the peaks are at x1, x2, x3,..., try `NIntegrate[f[x], {x, a, x1,x2, x3, ..., b}]`.  Also try `Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]`, if it's an `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 There's about 100 spikes, so putting the list in by hand is not very feasible.  (Besides, I would like something that I can easily scale as I use different numerically defined functions.)  They're also not truly singularities, just sharp peaks, so I'm not sure why using NIntegrate's singularity testing will help...

Comment: You can put the spikes in with code. What about the 2nd suggestion?

Comment: If `f[x]` is not an `InterpolatingFunction`, then perhaps `MinRecursion -> 2` or whatever lowest number works.  There are other parameters to play with, described in "tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules" and elsewhere.

Comment: Using N[Integrate[ ---- ]] runs for a long time without returning a result.  Changing minrecursion to a small number gives ncvb errors, because of the spikes.

Comment: `Integrate` (without `N`) integrates an `InterpolatingFunction` very quickly with no error due to integration (about as quickly as can be done).  If you're integrand is a formula involving interpolating functions, then it is the wrong approach.  As for ncvb, try following the advice in the message.

Comment: However, it falls back on numerical evaluation if you have a product/functional of several interpolating functions.

Comment: Yes, that's because your integrand is not an `InterpolatingFunction`.  (Perhaps it's not clear that I meant that literally.  It can't to be multiplied by something else, not added to something, just a simple lonely `IF`.)

Answer (score 2):

(If this doesn't help, then I think you will have to post your own example.)

Random data:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = Sort@
   Transpose[{{0, 1000}~Join~RandomReal[{0, 1000}, 10000 - 2], 
     RandomReal[{-5, -4}, 10000 - 100]~Join~RandomReal[{4, 5}, 100]}];

ifn = Interpolation[data]
```

For the integrand I'll use `ifn[x]^2`.  It does have about 100 spikes randomly placed:

```
Plot[ifn[x]^2, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 100000}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A naive application of `NIntegrate` complains:

```
NIntegrate[ifn[x]^2, {x, 0, 1000}]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {460.922}. NIntegrate obtained 44561.490415711516`and 6980.389951991658` for the integral and error estimates. >>

```
(*  44561.5  *)
```

Increasing `MinRecursion` changes the value -- there must be a problem:

```
NIntegrate[ifn[x]^2, {x, 0, 1000}, MinRecursion -> 1]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb:...

```
(*  54356.8  *)
```

At `MinRecursion -> 3` we get a `NIntegrate::slwcon` warning, which I take as a good sign and `NIntegrate` is getting some traction, and the value has crept up to `61409.`.  At `MinRecursion -> 4`, the value jumps up to `3.05019*10^8` - wow.  There is another way to go...

**Using the interpolating function**

An `InterpolationFunction` is basically a piecewise polynomial, a cubic one by default.  The method `ifn["Grid"]` tells you points where the polynomial changes.  So if `f[ifn[x]]` is well-behave (in our case `f[t] = t^2`), then the following should give good results, perhaps slowly:

```
NIntegrate[ifn[x]^2, Evaluate@Flatten@{x, ifn["Grid"]}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {8.024718, 2.07559*10^9}  *)
```

If the spikes are infrequent, we might be able to get away skipping some of the grid points, since `NIntegrate` is probably using the Gauss-Kronrod rule.  How much we can skip will depend on where the spikes are and the integrand.  It's hard to give a good rule of thumb.  The more we skip, the more likely that `NIntegrate` will have to recursively subdivide some parts of the domain of integration.  In this particular case, skipping every 10 works and speeds the calculation up by a factor of 8.

```
skip = 10;
NIntegrate[ifn[x]^2, 
  Evaluate@Flatten@{x, 0, ifn["Grid"][[2 ;; -2 ;; skip]], 
     1000}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.999823, 2.07559*10^9}  *)
```

**Back to `MinRecursion`**

We have to bump `MinRecursion` up to `10` to get a good result, that's still a wee bit off.

```
NIntegrate[ifn[x]^2, {x, 0, 1000}, MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 20] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {3.825013, 2.07558*10^9}  *)
```

At `MinRecursion -> 7` it converges to `NIntegrate`'s satisfaction, but the value `2.07401*10^9` is not too good.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is helpful, although since I have a product of interpolating functions not immediately...although I can probable merge the grids of the two...thanks!

Comment: @LaurenPearce  You're welcome.  Yes, something like `Evaluate@Flatten@{x, Union[{0., 1000.}, Flatten@ifn1["Grid"],  Flatten@ifn2["Grid"]]}` might work.

Answer (score 0):

As the following code suggests, a lot of spikes in the integrand means that several different numerical answers should be obtained when representing the data by means of more or less smooth functions (in the code the function is obtained by
`Interpolation` and its smoothness depends on the parameter named order):

```
a = -50;
b = 50;
Table[SeedRandom[5]; datax = RandomSample[Range[a, b, 0.1], 75];
      SeedRandom[5]; datay = RandomSample[Range[a, b, .5], 75];
data = Transpose[{datax, datay}];
p = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> order];
Print[Plot[Evaluate[p[x]], {x, a, b}, Frame -> True]];
Print["int=", NIntegrate[p[x], {x, First[datax], Last[datax]}]],
     {order, { 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6}}];
```